# Автозапуск маршрута в приложении Яндекс навигатор

Tags: яндекс-навигатор

Моё приложение открывает через URL API Яндекс навигатор, которое в свою очередь строит маршрут между точками. Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы маршрут запускался после открытия приложения и не нужно было нажимать "Поехали"? В документации по API этой информации не нашёл

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А в чем, собственно, вопрос?
Если у вас точки заранее известны, можно дергать [урл](https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/navigator/doc/concepts/navigator-url-params.html#navigator-url-params__openmap) при отрисовке экрана, например.